# How to make a Client in SNMP4J?

Tags: android, snmp, snmp4j

I need to make a Client in SNMP4J, but the documentation on how to get started is pretty poor. Does anyone have any experience with SNMP4J and could give me an idea on how to get started? Thanks.

Comment: For an open source project with samples, I wonder why not get started from the code.

Comment: I have tried using the code, but I am still having trouble understanding it and I am still confused about the testing. Could you give me some references about it?